# How to get the number of rows returned in a query before fetching the rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, relational-database, query-optimization

I need to perform a query and store the result in an array, but I have to know the number of rows to build the array.

The first idea is to append the row count to each row:

```
with truequery as (
    select ...
)
select q.*, (select count(*) from truequery)
from truequery q
```

The second idea is to move the cursor to the end and return to the beginning. The example is in Java

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
//...
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
rs.last();
int size = rs.getRow();
rs.beforeFirst();
Entity[] list = new Entity[size];
for (int i=0; rs.next(); i++){
    list[i] = new Entity(rs.getString(), ...);
}
```

If the query has `order by` or `group by`, the RDBMS is likely to know the number of rows before returning the first row.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `count(*) over ()` will return the count as column. Btw, afaik Teradata is the only DBMS which creates the full answer set first, before returning it to the client (and reports this count in the first message returned to the client).

Comment: @dnoeth `Teradata is the only DBMS which creates the full answer set first...` -- Interesting. I would generally consider this is a bad strategy. It's the opposite of the "pipelining" strategy that most engines try to promote (since it's less resource intensive).

Comment: @TheImpaler Teradata is a massive parallel system where pipelining is not that simple. And as long as you don't abort returning the answer set before the last row there's no real difference, you might have to wait a bit longer to get the first row. And if you add `count(*) over ()` every DBMS needs to produce the full answer set first :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the entities in a `java.util.List` and then convert it to an array. For example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query,
  ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
List<Entity> l = new ArrayList<Entity>();
while (rs.next())  {
  l.add(new Entity(rs.getString(), ...));
}
Entity[] list = l.toArray(new Entity[0]);
```

The overhead of the `List` should be minimal, since you want to load the whole query in memory anyway.